# Operator for validation for 2 options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I'm confused how to use if else statement. It's related to validation.

My below code worked for the first 2 field.

```
if(!name || name=='' &&
        !age || age=='' 
      ){
      console.log('failed to validate');
      return false;
    }
```

my 3rd field is the tricky one. They are `skipped` or `passed`. The field will appear either `skipped` or `passed`. How do I ensure they got validated? I can't do `!skipped || skipped == '' && !passed || passed == ''` this surely will failed.

Comment: Understand that `&&` binds more tightly than `||`, so you may need to introduce explicit parentheses to enforce the proper order of evaluation.

Comment: please elaborate.

Comment: in your validation, include the condition that leads to the respective fields being displayed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
if(!name || name=='' 
  && !age || age=='' 
  && ((!skipped || skipped == '') 
      || (!passed || passed == ''))
  ){
  console.log('failed to validate');
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use functions when deciding whether to display the respective input fields and when validating:

```
function isPassedNeeded(){
  return someBool;
}
function isSkippedNeeded(){
  return someOtherBool;
}
```

Validation could look like

```
if(isPassedNeeded() && (!passed || passed == ''){
   // fail
}
// same for the other field...
```

However, this way is pretty non-dynamic. You could think about some dynamic attributes (e.g. using the `input`'s `class`) or check for the visibility of fields before validating them.